# ElasticSearch add sorting attribute to mget call

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mget call in ElasticSearch to get specific documents

```
{
    "index" : appConfig.ElasticSearch.Module.index,
    "type" : appConfig.ElasticSearch.Module.type,
    "body" : {
      "ids": modulesIds
     }
}
```

how can I sort the resulted documents on some 'xyz' attribute of the document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Instead, why don't you do it like this, if you already know the IDs:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [
            "1","2","3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "whatever": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```